# Passing dynamic data from a while loop to other modules

Tags: python, loops, scope

I have a function below that should be constantly running every second, making API calls and receiving data. Api_data is an instance of a class defined separately. I am building a list with 5 most recent data points. I want to be able to use my_DataPoints in other functions and modules, for example to build a JSON with the received recent data, and I am not sure how to pass and access its value. I defined global variables, but I am not sure if this is the correct way and how to import them. I would appreciate your help.

```py
    def get_data(api_data):
        interval = 5
        global my_DataPoints
        global myData
        my_DataPoints = []
        myData = {}
            
        while True:
            for x in range(interval):
                start = time.time()
                myData = api_data
                print(myData.rTime)
                my_DataPoints.append(myData)
                        
                if (len(my_DataPoints) - 1) == interval:
                    my_DataPoints.pop(0)
                print(my_DataPoints)  
                    
                    
                end = time.time()
                if (end - start) < 1:
                    time.sleep(1 - (end - start))
```

Comment: If the issue more about concurrent processing or is it about how to maintain and accessible history?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using global variables, you can define your `get_data` function to return the `my_DataPoints` list after it's done collecting the data. Then, you can assign the returned list to a variable in your main script, which you can then pass to other functions.

Here's an example of how you can modify your `get_data` function to return the `my_DataPoints` list:

```py
def get_data(api_data):
    interval= 5
    my_DataPoints= []
    myData = {}
        
    while True:
        for x in range(interval):
            start= time.time()
            myData= api_data
            print(myData.rTime)
            my_DataPoints.append(myData)
                    
            if (len(my_DataPoints)-1) ==interval:
                my_DataPoints.pop(0)
            print(my_DataPoints)  
                
                
            end= time.time()
            if (end -start) < 1:
                time.sleep(1-(end-start))
                
        yield my_DataPoints
```

In your main script, you can then call the function and assign the returned list to a variable like this:

```py
api_data = ApiData()  # assuming ApiData is the class for your API data
data_points = get_data(api_data)  # get the generator object

while True:
    my_DataPoints = next(data_points)  # get the next set of data points
    # do something with my_DataPoints, e.g. build a JSON object
    time.sleep(1)  # wait for 1 second before getting the next set of data points
```

Note that `get_data` now returns a generator object that yields the `my_DataPoints` list every `interval` seconds. The next function is used to retrieve the next set of data points. You can then use the `my_DataPoints` list as needed in your main script.

Comment: thank you. I have not even though about using yield. I am implementing the solution now.